# Passing Key,Value into a Function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I want to check a YouTube video's views and keep track of them over time. I wrote a script that works great:

```
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import time

def check_views(link):
    todays_date = datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m')
    now_time = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')

    #get the site
    r = requests.get(link)
    text = r.text
    tag = re.compile('\d+ views')
    views = re.findall(tag,text)[0]
    
    #get the digit number of views. It's returned in a list so I need to get that item out
    cleaned_views=re.findall('\d+',views)[0]
    print(cleaned_views)

    
    #append to the df
    df.loc[len(df)] = [todays_date, now_time, int(cleaned_views)]
    #df = df.append([todays_date, now_time, int(cleaned_views)],axis=0)

    
    df.to_csv('views.csv')
    return df

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date','Time','Views'])

while True:
     df = check_views('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPHgRp70H8o&t=3s')
     time.sleep(1800)
```

But now I want to use this function for multiple links. I want a different CSV file for each link. So I made a dictionary:

```
link_dict = {'link1':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPHgRp70H8o&t=3s',
             'link2':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZPrAKuOBWzw'}
#this makes it easy for each csv file to be named for the corresponding link
```

The loop then becomes:

```
for key, value in link_dict.items():
    df = check_views(value)
```

That seems to work passing the value of the dict (link) into the function. Inside the function, I just made sure to load the correct csv file at the beginning:

```
#Existing csv files
df=pd.read_csv(k+'.csv')
```

But then I'm getting an error when I go to append a new row to the df (“cannot set a row with mismatched columns”). I don't get that since it works just fine as the code written above. This is the part giving me an error:

```
df.loc[len(df)] = [todays_date, now_time, int(cleaned_views)]
```

What am I missing here? It seems like a super messy way using this dictionary method (I only have 2 links I want to check but rather than just duplicate a function I wanted to experiment more). Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: When I run the code, I get an error - regex doesn't find any information about the views. Are you sure the code is correct?

Comment: Really? I just copy/pasted this and it works fine (it actually is only returning the number 514 with a video with 6,000,514 views--but the actual links I'm using have 2 digit views so it works for my case).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! The problem was that I was saving the df as a csv and then trying to read back that csv later. When I saved the csv, I didn't use `index=False` with df.to_csv() so there was an extra column! When I was just testing with the dictionary, I was just reusing the df and even though I was saving it to a csv, the script kept using the df to do the actual adding of rows.